# Using Jiffle To Compute Maximum Value For All Bands

Tags: geoserver, jiffle

Within GeoServer, I have an ImageMosaic store that is providing a set of grayscale images that match the current time/elevation criteria. I am using the STACK merge stray so I can obtain all the raw values. I am attempting to use Jiffle inside of an SLD style to determine the maximum value of all bands that are being provided as inputs.  If I know the number of bands that are coming in, I can explicitly call them out and do this:

```
<ogc:Literal>
  dest = max(src[0], src[1])
</ogc:Literal>
```

but I don't always know how many bands are coming in.  I have tried passing the whole `src` variable to the max but I get an Internal Compiler Error in the logs.  I have tried switching to a `foreach` loop but `src` isn't valid there either.

Is there a way to determine how many items are in the input list?  Or is there another way for me to determine the maximum value from all the input bands?

Answer (score 0):

I looked through the source code for the Jiffle RasterProcess and found this is not possible.  I ended up creating a new RasterProcess plugin which allowed me to access the entire listing of bands and implement the desired functionality.